# Draw bitmap over activity in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, adb

Is it possible to draw a bit map or an image over application that is running on the phone. The problem is that there is no access to that application source code.

Comment: @user1379574 Do you know it's package name?

Comment: for example, I know it. It is possible case.

Comment: If you want draw something over other applications, I think you cant.

Comment: Isn't is possible to do in some system level?

Comment: you can use an intent handler to do this in some cases but this only applies when the application send a request to OS to handle certain data (examples play video, share link etc.) genereally know you cannot though

Comment: @user1379574 at some system level yes anything is possible basically but if your planning to write an application no.. or are you thinking of writing a custom kernel to do this .. note no one will use it most likely unless your planning to sell hardware with it

Comment: For example, if I put anther way: I do not overlay the application, but make it not take the whole screen and put my image for example on the too. Can I do so?

Comment: Is possible by writing custom os version?

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of running App's by `ActivityManager`.So if you know name of desired App,you can create a service that checks list of running Apps periodically and if it is run,show your image.It will be easy to show you image:Create an Activity and set a layout for it that contains your image then start it from your service when desired App is run.

Comment: How to show this image over this app? could you provide me with some piece of code please?

Comment: But in this case the newly created activity will take all the screen?

Comment: @user1379574 You can change position and size of your Activity by overriding `onAttachToWindow()` method.Also you can set transparent some area of layout of your Activity,so user can see background Activity.

Comment: that's interesting idea, I will try it, thank you. If you don't mind I will message you if I have any questions.

Comment: the problem is that after I draw the image, I have to be still able to work with previous activity...that's why variant with transparent style doesn't suit. Can I say the same about overriding onAttachedWindow()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27092/discussion-between-user1379574-and-hasanghaforian)